# Some trouble about Object.create() and prototype chain?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

there is 2 piece of code:

```
var obj1 = {name:'one'};
obj2 = Object.create(obj1);
obj2.name = 'two';
console.log(obj1.name);                 //one


var obj1 = {prop:{name:'one'}};
obj2 = Object.create(obj1);
obj2.prop.name = 'two';
console.log(obj1.prop.name);            //two
```

why the output of clause 2 is two?

Comment: You've just set `obj1` as the **prototype** of `obj2`, that's why !

Comment: obj2.prop resolves to the prototype. So setting its name edits it.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you are using `obj1` as the prototype. When it's used, it does a **shallow** copy of the object. That means that the top-level is different (i.e., if you change `obj2.prop`, it won't affect `obj1.prop`, but the lower levels are references to the same things, so changing them causes things to change.

It's the same with `Object.assign()`:

```js
// Shallow-copy of one level, don't affect each other
const obj1 = { a: 1 };
const obj2 = Object.assign({}, obj1);
obj2.a = 2;
console.log(obj1.a, obj2.a);

// Shallow-copy, change top-level, don't affect each other
const obj3 = { a: { b: 1 } };
const obj4 = Object.assign({}, obj3);
obj4.a = 3;
console.log(obj3.a, obj4.a);

// Shallow-copy, change inner object, affects each other
const obj5 = Object.assign({}, obj3);
obj5.a.b = 2;
console.log(obj3.a.b, obj5.a.b);
```

If you want to avoid changing it with something multiple levels down, you'll need to do a deep copy/clone.

(There are lots of different libraries out there that implement such a function, so I won't re-implement one here.)